# Flash in Win8 Store app using JavaScript + html5

Tags: javascript, html, flash, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I use JavaScript + html5 for create Win8 Store app. I need to open .swf file in my app. Swf file is downloading from our server on boot time. Swf file is local after boot. I wonder if it is possible to embed a flash control in a app? I tried but it seems it doesn't work... (have tried iframe too) 
I try to open swf file in Metro IE by this code:

```
> var file = 'flashobject.html';
>             Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync(file).then(function
> (file) {
>                 var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
>                 options.displayApplicationPicker = true;
> 
>                 Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file, options).then(function (success) {
>                     if (success) {
>                         // Yay!
>                         console.log('Success');
>                     } else {
>                         // FROWN :(
>                         console.log('Failure');
>                     }
>                 });
>             });
```

This Html code:

```
    <body>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab">
            <param name="autoplay" value="false">
            <param name="movie" value="candles_Pp.swf">
            <object class="iehide" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashobject_files/candles_.swf">
                <param name="controller" value="true">
                <param name="autoplay" value="false">   
                <param name="pluginurl" value="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">          
                <a href="http://www.yourwebskills.com/files/examples/candles_Pp.swf">Your browser is not able to handle this media here so use this link to play the file in an external application </a>
            </object>
        </object>
</body>
```

Is there any way to open swf file, mayby there any api for convert swf to html at boot time.

Comment: I am trying to solv the same trouble from 3 days and two nights and read a lot of stuff, but it can't be work on my flash. Because my flash is little bit complex. May be this can convert your flash into HTML5 Code. Must try it out: https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/

Answer (score 1):

The IE10 emulator used to render Win8 Store Applications written in javascript does not support any plugins. You need to convert your swf to an acceptable `HTML5 video` format (`.mp4`) and play the video using an `HTML5 video` tag.

Comment: Swf file store on the server and it's can't be converted. Can we convert swf file at clien app to an acceptable html5 format?